# Activate or add class active on menu tab link when clicking the menu link with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to Activate or add class active on menu tab link when clicking the menu link with Jquery and:
I have HTML

```
<div id="top" class="shadow">
<ul class="gprc"> 
<li><a href="http://www.domain.com/">Home</a></li> 
<li><a href="http://www.domain.com/link1/">Text1</a></li> 
<li><a href="http://www.domain.com/link2/">Text2</a></li> 
<li><a href="http://www.domain.com/link3/">Text3</a></li> 
<li><a href="http://www.domain.com/link4">Text4</a></li> 
</ul> 
</div>
```

And i found the following script for doing so.
JQuery

```
$( document).ready(function (){
  $( function(){
   var url = window.location.pathname,
   urlRegExp = new RegExp(url.replace( /\/$/,'' ) + "$" );
   $('a').each( function(){
   if(urlRegExp.test(this .href.replace(/\/$/, ''))){
    $( this).addClass('active' );
  }
 });   
});
});
```

JUST that it does it for the entire web page, how could i do it only for the specified menu that i posted in HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$(function () {
    var url = window.location.pathname,
        urlRegExp = new RegExp(url.replace(/\/$/, '') + "$");
    $('#top a').each(function () {
        if (urlRegExp.test(this.href.replace(/\/$/, ''))) {
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }
    });    
});
```

Adding the `active` class to only the proper link inside `div` with the **ID** as `top`, using the proper selector `$('#top a')`, instead of implementing it on all the links on the page.

Comment: There is a problem, when i click on "home" or link1 i am getting all the active tabs.

Comment: @Adrian I had the same problem. I solved it by removing ".replace(/\/$/, '')" in both places.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify that you want for that to work only if it is a anchor element inside 'gprc' ul element like that:

```
$('.gprc a').each( function(){
   if(urlRegExp.test(this .href.replace(/\/$/, ''))){
    $( this).addClass('active' );
  }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try scoping your selector to only anchor tags within your menu's div.

e.g.:

```
$( document).ready(function (){
  $( function(){
    var url = window.location.pathname, urlRegExp = new RegExp(url.replace( /\/$/,'' ) + "$" );
    $('#top a').each( function(){
      if(urlRegExp.test(this .href.replace(/\/$/, ''))){
        $( this).addClass('active' );
      }
    });   
  });
});
```